# how to ensure windows shared memory is alive?

Tags: shared-memory, boost-interprocess

i have an App running in windows，and i create an shared_memory (with boost/interprocess) to act as a cache to supply some infos to the app. when i use the shared_memory, i had to insure the shard_memory is alive， indetail that i have to ensure i can get right date from shard_data in below.

```
shmObjWin = new windows_shared_memory(create_only, trueFileName, read_write, max_memory);
shmRegion = new mapped_region(*(context->shmObjWin), read_write);
shared_data = new(context->shmRegion->get_address()) shared_data_t;
```

My question is "how to ensure windows  shared memory is alive?"

Thanks a lot.